# Saving ggplot within dplyr?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dply statement which outputs a ggplot.  Here's the basic idea:

```
my_data  %>%
  group_by(group1) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(group1, n), y=n)) + 
  #geom_segment(aes(xend = reorder(group1, n), y = 0 , yend = n), lineend = "round", size = 10, color="#E48312") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#E48312")
```

However, I want to display the ggplots in a grid.  So when I try:

```
grid.arrange(my_data,
             my_data, 
             ncol=2)
```

I get:

```
Error: Input must be a vector, not a `viewport` object. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How can I save the ggplot as a plot within the dplyr statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to assign to a new object

```
out <- my_data  %>%
  group_by(group1) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(group1, n), y=n)) + 
  #geom_segment(aes(xend = reorder(group1, n), y = 0 , yend = n), 
  #          lineend = "round", size = 10, color="#E48312") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#E48312") 
grid.arrange(out, out, ncol=2)
```

Comment: Well dang.  When I call grid.arrange using "knit" in rmarkdown, I now get an error: Error in Eval: object not found.  When I run the chunk itself, it runs fine.  any ideas?

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 the error shows that you may not have the object created in the global env.  Is that case.  Do you have `my_data` in that env

Comment: oh wait think i figured it out.  I had eval=false when defining 'out'.  think i'm good.  Thanks!

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 yes, then it wouldn't `eval`uate the whole chunk :=).   I normally create a input chunk at the top and create a relevant name like `grp_eval <- TRUE` and then in the specific chunk `eval = grp_eval` so that I only need to change the input arguments.  Also, if you want to evaluate but not want to include use `include = FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

Am I misunderstanding, or can you just assign each plot a name in the environment like this?

```
plot_1 <- my_data  %>%
  group_by(group1) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(group1, n), y=n)) + 
  #geom_segment(aes(xend = reorder(group1, n), y = 0 , yend = n), lineend = "round", size = 10, color="#E48312") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#E48312") 

plot_2 <- my_data  %>%
  group_by(group1) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(group1, n), y=n)) + 
  #geom_segment(aes(xend = reorder(group1, n), y = 0 , yend = n), lineend = "round", size = 10, color="#E48312") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#E48312") 

grid.arrange(plot_1,
             plot_2, 
             ncol=2)
```